# My iphone app pilot available to download outside of apps store

Tags: html, iphone, xcode

I have a server at work that I want to host an iphone application on.

I want it so that the user goes to the web browser on their ihpone and clicks a download link on a html page and iphone application is installed on their phone.

Is there any way that this is possible using xocde? Perhaps some way I can build a .plist file that does this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot install a native iPhone application without going through the App Store (unless you wish to publish your app solely to jailbroken devices). If you really don't want to use the app store, you can build a web app that runs on the server, but you cannot install and run arbitrary binaries on a users device that have not been approved by Apple.

EDIT: As people have pointed out, there are options for testing purposes that will allow you to install your app on other devices via the internet (TestFlightApp, iOS Enterprise program), but for a wide-scale deployment technique this will not work.

Comment: While you are correct, it is not the whole picture. One way, you can register the devices and deploy OTA using TestFlightApp.com. Another way is to subscribe to Apple's enterprise program. Of course, both have limitations but it does what the person asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Jumhyn is right in his answer but there is a little more to it.

If you want your App to be available to iPhone users (non-jailbroken) you have to have an [Apple developer account](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/) ($99/yr)

If you want to develop only for jailbroken devices you can, but i'm not sure about the license agreements you accept when using Xcode and Cocoa(touch) framework. It might be a violation of your agreement.

The last solution is the [Apple Enterprise developer program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) ($299/yr). Here you can control who has access to your app and I think it is possible to distribute around the App Store. There is definitely some limitation.

One thing is sure. You cannot do installation from websites as you want without going around Apple's App Store. I strongly recommend sticking to the rules and agreements you accepted when activating OS X, Xcode, iPhone and the Cocoa Framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to permanently deploy to a website, this will not work for legitimate App Store applications. You can however, once published to the app store, place a link to to it that will take them to the AppStore for downloading it.

If you need this for testing/beta purposes I reccommend [www.testflightapp.com](http://www.testflightapp.com)